# what am I doing wrong here? modal page + redirect and set value checksum error

Tags: oracle-apex, checksum

```
Page Item: P1_ITEM_1
Type: Select List
Page Action on Selection: Redirect and Set Value
```

It works fine if **Page Mode** is **Normal**. However, if I change it to **Modal Dialog**, it gives below checksum error on item selections.

```
apex_error_code: APEX.SESSION_STATE.SSP_VIOLATION2_FOR_DEVELOPERS
```

right after submitting the page.

No weird dynamic actions or scripts on the page.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is expected behaviour. A modal page cannot be opened directly, in needs to be invoked from a parent page - that is how modal pages work. A redirect to a modal page is exactly the same as opening it directly so I'd expect it to fail.

Comment: I think I was expecting it to be failed too. But it looked 2x beautiful in modal page :)